# Firestore - adding object with an array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

killing myself with this thing in here all day, I'm having two classes Department and Articals :

```
export class Department {
articals?: Artical[]=[];
moms?: number;
id?: string;
constructor() {
}
}
```

and:

```
export class Artical {

moms?: number;
price: number;
name?: string;

constructor() {
}
}
```

like You can see departments contains an Array of 'Articals'
so I am building new Department with new articals(and their properties) and trying to add it to fireStore with:

```
this.departmetsCollection.doc(departmentId).set(Object.assign({}, 
myDepartment));
```

but getting Error : 
"Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Artical object"

P.s tryed add only array of articals to the path of department as

```
doc(departmentId).set({'articals':myArticals});
```

and with 'update' instead of 'set' but no help either:S
what is teh correct of adding that kind of object to firestore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firestore only  accepts  a JavaScript object embedded within a document if it is a “pure” object, this means you can't use custom objects while developing in TypeScript. So you would have to map your objects before push them to the articals array.

First change your Department class:

```
export class Department {
articals?: Array<any>=[];
moms?: number;
id?: string;
constructor() {
}
}
```

Second map your array of "Artical":

```
var map = arrayOfArtical.map((obj)=> {return Object.assign({}, obj)});
```

Then you can attribute the map value to 'this.myDepartment.articals'

```
this.myDepartment.articals  = map;
```

After that you can execute:

```
this.departmetsCollection.doc(departmentId).set(Object.assign({}, 
myDepartment))
```

Comment: ty for explenation sir , helped alot (y)